# Bat file launch in remote machine via PowerShell scripts

Tags: powershell

**Aim:** I wish to launch a bat file in remote machine to see the execution visibly.

I have the below code which executes the bat file and printing the logs in PowerShell console but NOT launching in the remote machine where I wanted.

```
workflow RunScripts {
parallel {
InlineScript { 
    $User = "foo\boo"
    $PWord = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "koo" -AsPlainText -Force
    $Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $PWord
    Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value "*" -Force
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName "11.111.111.222" -ScriptBlock {cmd /c "\\11.111.111.222\c$\foo\boo\Node.bat"} -Credential $Credential -ErrorAction Stop
   } 
}
}
RunScripts
```

Could someone guide? as to what changes I need to make the launching in remote machine before execution.

Points to remember: Execution happens successfully in remote machine but bat file is not launching visibly to see the execution there.

Comment: Replace `"\\11.111.111.222\c$\foo\boo\Node.bat"` with `"C:\foo\boo\Node.bat"` - no need to use a UNC path for the remote filesystem _when you're already executing on the remote computer_ :)

Comment: Mathias solution is using a dollar sign instead of normal colon.  The dollar sign will run remote bat as Admin.  You also need to start powershell as Admin.  So right click Powershell shortcut and select Run As Admin.  The run code with dollar sign.

Comment: Mathias suggestion should be all that's needed given permissions are appropriate. What is the purpose of placing this in a workflow? Seems you're setting the listener properties for connections inbound, but that wouldn't fix remoting to another computer; *just as an fyi*.

Comment: All the above given recommendation leads to successful execution but still the bat file is not getting launched for me to see in remote machine.

Comment: Also you can run a local powershell script on a remote machine:  `invoke-command computer001 localscript.ps1`

Comment: You have to run it as the logged in user or else it won’t show in that session.

Comment: ^ this is what's needed. The script needs to be ran in the users context to see the actual output on that logged on session

Answer (score 0):

Learner,

Try using Enter-PSSession. The following test script worked successfully displaying the directory list of the target machine on the initiating machine's display.

```
Clear-Host
$SessionID = New-PSSession -ComputerName DellXPS8700
Enter-PSSession $SessionID
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {g:\BEKDocs\Batch\TestSize.cmd}
Exit-PSSession 
$SessionID = $Null
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am looking for a solution that launches an application (Eg. bat file) in remote machine. The current solution of mine executes the content of the bat file in remote machine successfully but the bat file is not being visually opened there to see.

Comment: Learner, I tried it with a .vbs file and it worked don't see why it wouldn't work with a .bat file.

Comment: Learner, I tried it with a .bat file successfully. Answer above modified to reflect that.

Comment: Do you see ".bat" file is getting launched visually in your remote machine while being executed? Reason is, the above solution does execute the bat file successfully but the file is not getting launched (Like after double click the file) visually to see there.

Comment: Learner, I'm not sure what you mean by "see it getting launched". You'll only see any output from the program, if the program has not output you won't see anything.